# Redirect local request to another file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect a file to another file, but I don't understand htaccess enough to get it working.

Basically, for example, if someone accesses `mysite.com/i/somefile.png` I need it to redirect to `mysite.com/view.php?i=somefile` (without the .png extension)

I'm also trying to set it so that this process only happens local requests, so if the image is embedded on another site, it wont be redirected.

If someone could provide the code for this, and also explain it a bit so I have a better understanding for future use, I'd appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mysite\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !/view\.php
RewriteRule ^/?i/(.+)\.png$ http://mysite\.com/view.php?i=$1 [L]
```

And accessing the image from the direct link redirects to view.php, and embedding still works.

Thanks for the help Jon Lin

Answer (score 1):

Try adding these rules to the htaccess file in your **document root**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} mysite.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !/view\.php
RewriteRule ^/?i/(.+)\.png$ /view.php?i=$1 [L]
```

Note that this is going to make it so embedded images via the `<img src=` tags will also get internally rewritten.

---

> the issue being (like you said), image embedding for that page doesn't work now. Is there any way to make the embedding work?

You can try making `<a>` links different than `<img>` links by modifying the prefix and rewriting those:

For example:

```
<a href="/a/something.png">
   <img src="/i/something.png">
</a>
```

Then:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?a/(.+)\.png$ /view.php?i=$1 [L]
```

Comment: The first condition seems incorrect. I removed it and it worked for the most part, the issue being (like you said), image embedding for that page doesn't work now. Is there any way to make the embedding work? I don't necessarily need to have the URL appear as .png, so a standard redirect would be fine, if that's possible.

Comment: I don't think that will work for what I'm trying to do. I just took a harder look at the second condition and noticed what you were trying to do. From my understanding, if the page is 
`mysite.com/view.php` then it shouldn't be rewriting, correct? If so, I think that will work, we just have to get the right code (the first condition isn't working either, so I assume they're both broken for the same reason)

Comment: @user1368667 The `RewriteRule ^/?a/(.+)\.png$ /view.php?i=$1 [L]` rule only rewrites requests that start with `/a/`, which you use in `<a>` tags, the actual embedded images would remain `/i/image.png` while in the `<a>` tags the links would be `/a/image.png`

Comment: That would defeat the purpose though, since the whole reason I'm doing this is to redirect images in /i/ to view.php. I think you were on to something with the second condition above, we just need to figure out how to get it working. I do appreciate all the help so far :)

Comment: @user1368667 there is no way to tell the difference between a request for an image via an embedded `<img>` tag versuse a request for an image via a link. The referers will be identical.